# Jquery unbind() not working for contact form

Tags: javascript, jquery, unbind

I am building my first contact form.

I am trying to unbind my function given no error message.
Code is below - for whatever reason I keep getting the follow error message in my dev console :

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).unbind is not a function

Appreciate any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class ='container'>
    <h1>Get in touch!</h1>

    <div id='error'></div>

      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Subject</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleTextarea">Message</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>

    </div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $('form').submit(function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();
      var error ="";

      if ($('#subject').val() == "") {
        error += 'The subject field is required.<br>';
      }

      if ($('#message').val() == "") {
        error += 'The message field is required.<br>';
      }


      if ($('#email').val() == "") {
        error += 'The email field is required.';
      }

      if (error != "" ) {
        $("#error").html(
        '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"></p> <strong>Error(s) in your form:</strong></p>' + error +  '</div>');
      }else{
        $("form").unbind('submit').submit();
      }

    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want to do with this line :  `$("form").unbind('submit').submit();`

Comment: Looks like `$("form").unbind('submit').submit();` should be replaced by `$("form").off('submit');`... If OP to disable any future submit attempt. **OR** simply removed, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `3.1.1.slim` build of jQuery. According to [the jQuery site](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/):

> [the slim build] "...**excludes** ajax, effects, and **currently deprecated code**."

The [`.unbind()` method](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) was deprecated in v3.0, and so is not included in the build you are using.

Use [the `.off()` method](http://api.jquery.com/off/) instead.